# How to plot FancyBboxPatch in physical units without it getting cut off?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot my data as physical units of inches (that is, I have data in "points", which I can convert to inches).  (I looked at the matplotlib transforms tutorial.)  In the code below, I would like to be able to auto-compute the figsize needed.  In order to do this, I hard-code three variables, WIDTH_SHIFT, HEIGHT_SHIFT, and PORTION_OF_PLOT_INSIDE_THE_MARGINS.  These values work for this example, however, as the figure gets bigger, I need to increase the SHIFT variables, and possibly also need to alter the PORTION variable.  I would like to auto-compute those, if possible, or find an alternative method.  If I set WIDTH_SHIFT and HEIGHT_SHIFT to zero, then the ABCDEFG and F node boxes are not plotted correctly.  They fall outside the axes.  The ABCDEFG box is partially drawn.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import BoxStyle, FancyBboxPatch


# Set-up the node data

node_width_ABCDEFG = 116/72  # inches
node_height_ABCDEFG = 28/72  # inches
node_center_x_ABCDEFG = 0 + 58/72  # inches
node_center_y_ABCDEFG = 3 + 14/72  # inches
lower_left_corner_ABCDEFG = [
    node_center_x_ABCDEFG - node_width_ABCDEFG/2,
    node_center_y_ABCDEFG - node_height_ABCDEFG/2]

node_width_F = 28/72  # inches
node_height_F = 28/72  # inches
node_center_x_F = 3 + 14/72  # inches
node_center_y_F = 0 + 14/72  # inches
lower_left_corner_F = [node_center_x_F - node_width_F/2,
                       node_center_y_F - node_height_F/2]

node_width_E = 28/72  # inches
node_height_E = 28/72  # inches
node_center_x_E = 5 + 14/72  # inches
node_center_y_E = 4 + 14/72  # inches
lower_left_corner_E = [node_center_x_E - node_width_E/2,
                       node_center_y_E - node_height_E/2]

node_width_C = 28/72  # inches
node_height_C = 28/72  # inches
node_center_x_C = 2.8 + 14/72  # inches  
node_center_y_C = 4.4 + 14/72  # inches
lower_left_corner_C = [node_center_x_C - node_width_C/2,
                       node_center_y_C - node_height_C/2]

# Compute size parameters needed to create the figure

# left edge of box ABCDEFG to right edge of box E
network_width_inches = (
    (node_center_x_E + node_width_E/2) - 
    (node_center_x_ABCDEFG - node_width_ABCDEFG/2))

# top edge of box C to bottom edge of box F
network_height_inches = (
    (node_center_y_C + node_height_C/2) - 
    (node_center_y_F - node_height_F/2))

print("network width inches: ", network_width_inches)
print("network height inches: ", network_height_inches)

WIDTH_SHIFT = .75  # width of left margin 
HEIGHT_SHIFT = 0.5  # height of bottom margin

# when these are zero, 
# the node boxes for ABCDEFG and F fall outside the axes
# WIDTH_SHIFT = 0  
# HEIGHT_SHIFT = 0

PORTION_OF_PLOT_INSIDE_THE_MARGINS = .7

fig_width_inches = 
    network_width_inches/PORTION_OF_PLOT_INSIDE_THE_MARGINS
fig_height_inches = 
    network_height_inches/PORTION_OF_PLOT_INSIDE_THE_MARGINS

# These enlargements are not big enough
# fig_width_inches = network_width_inches + 2*WIDTH_SHIFT
# fig_height_inches = network_height_inches + 2*HEIGHT_SHIFT

print("fig width inches: ", fig_width_inches)
print("fig height inches: ", fig_height_inches)

# Create the figure

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fig_width_inches, fig_height_inches), dpi=72)

ax = plt.gca()

# Plotting in inches

# Create the node boxes

node_patch_ABCDEFG = FancyBboxPatch(
        [lower_left_corner_ABCDEFG[0] + WIDTH_SHIFT, 
         lower_left_corner_ABCDEFG[1] + HEIGHT_SHIFT],
        node_width_ABCDEFG,
        node_height_ABCDEFG,
        edgecolor="blue",
        facecolor="lightblue",
        linewidth=1,
        boxstyle=BoxStyle("round", 
                          pad=0,
                          rounding_size=.1),
        transform=fig.dpi_scale_trans
        )

node_patch_C = FancyBboxPatch(
        [lower_left_corner_C[0] + WIDTH_SHIFT, 
         lower_left_corner_C[1] + HEIGHT_SHIFT],
        node_width_C,
        node_height_C,
        edgecolor="blue",
        facecolor="lightblue",
        linewidth=1,
        boxstyle=BoxStyle("round", 
                          pad=0,
                          rounding_size=.1),
        transform=fig.dpi_scale_trans
        )

node_patch_E = FancyBboxPatch(
        [lower_left_corner_E[0] + WIDTH_SHIFT, 
         lower_left_corner_E[1] + HEIGHT_SHIFT],
        node_width_E,
        node_height_E,
        edgecolor="blue",
        facecolor="lightblue",
        linewidth=1,
        boxstyle=BoxStyle("round", 
                          pad=0,
                          rounding_size=.1),
        transform=fig.dpi_scale_trans
        )            

node_patch_F = FancyBboxPatch(
        [lower_left_corner_F[0] + WIDTH_SHIFT, 
         lower_left_corner_F[1] + HEIGHT_SHIFT],
        node_width_F,
        node_height_F,
        edgecolor="blue",
        facecolor="lightblue",
        linewidth=1,
        boxstyle=BoxStyle("round", 
                          pad=0,
                          rounding_size=.1),
        transform=fig.dpi_scale_trans
        )

ax.add_patch(node_patch_ABCDEFG)
ax.add_patch(node_patch_C)
ax.add_patch(node_patch_E)
ax.add_patch(node_patch_F)

# Add text labels for the nodes

plt.text(
    node_center_x_ABCDEFG + WIDTH_SHIFT,
    node_center_y_ABCDEFG + HEIGHT_SHIFT,
    "ABCDEFG",
    fontsize=12,
    color="black",
    fontname="Verdana",
    fontstyle="normal",
    horizontalalignment="center",
    verticalalignment="center",
    transform=fig.dpi_scale_trans
    )

plt.text(
    node_center_x_C + WIDTH_SHIFT,
    node_center_y_C + HEIGHT_SHIFT,
    "C",
    fontsize=12,
    color="black",
    fontname="Verdana",
    fontstyle="normal",
    horizontalalignment="center",
    verticalalignment="center",
    transform=fig.dpi_scale_trans
    )

plt.text(
    node_center_x_E + WIDTH_SHIFT,
    node_center_y_E + HEIGHT_SHIFT,
    "E",
    fontsize=12,
    color="black",
    fontname="Verdana",
    fontstyle="normal",
    horizontalalignment="center",
    verticalalignment="center",
    transform=fig.dpi_scale_trans
    )

plt.text(
    node_center_x_F + WIDTH_SHIFT,
    node_center_y_F + HEIGHT_SHIFT,
    "F",
    fontsize=12,
    color="black",
    fontname="Verdana",
    fontstyle="normal",
    horizontalalignment="center",
    verticalalignment="center",
    transform=fig.dpi_scale_trans
    )

plt.axis("equal")

#plt.axis("off")

plt.show()

fig.savefig("node_example.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

[node boxes drawn correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUSGX.png)

[after subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1) and SHIFTS to 0 and PORTION to 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtCn2.png)

[removed bbox_inches="tight" from savefig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHz80.png)

[after subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1) in iPython console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqAyM.png)

Comment: Not really clear what you're doing here, I would start by making the axes visible, that is, someplace in your code you turned the axis spines etc off. Turn them on as long as you're not satisfied with the final result. If you need further help, a  [mcve] is needed.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I edited my question, added code which creates an example, and attached the plot it creates.  I have the axes turned on.

Comment: Set `fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)`, so that the axes sits tight against the figure.

Comment: I added fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1) just after the fig=plt.figure(...) line, and it's not pretty.  I uploaded the image I get.

Comment: Interesting. I would remove `bbox_inches` argument from `savefig` because the will apperently screw up a lot.

Comment: I am using matplotlib 3.0.2 on ubuntu.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. So the last picture is what I would expect. If that isn't what you're after, some deeper explanation is needed.

Comment: I removed the bbox_inches="tight", and uploaded the image.  Ok, right.  It does look right.  I was thrown-off by what I was I seeing in the spyder/iPython console, which does not look good.  Can I adjust that too?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of how the graph looks in iPython console, after the subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1).  I have seen another post saying that subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1) doesn't work with iPython console.  I need this to display interactively.

Comment: Not interactively, but "inline" you mean? In that case `%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}` would probably help. I'm pretty much lost at what exactly your code is doing and why it does it that way, so maybe there is an overall better solution.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the ImportanceOfBeingErnest,

The solution is to remove the margins from the figure, which can be done via:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)
```

in which case no values need to be set to shift the graph of nodes out of the margins into the axes or to make the figure larger than the graph itself.

For this to work when saving a figure, the

```
bbox_inches
```

parameter should not be used in

```
fig.savefig()
```

For this to work inline with an iPython console, use this command:

```
%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}
```